call a PL/SQL function from java /spring boot
I Have a PL/SQL function which is taking 3 parameters and returning boolean
Below is the part of code snipp
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IS_EMPLOYEE_EXISTS(
EMP_ID IN EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID%TYPES
EMP_NAME IN EMPLOYEE.EMP_NAME%TYPES
EMP_CATEGORY IN EMPLOYEE.EMP_CATEGORY%TYPES)
RETURN BOOLEAN
-- performing some operations based on the inputs given

Now my task is to call this function from my java class using spring jdbc
I am not able to call this as Jdbc drivers don't support pl/sql boolean types
my approach of calling this function is as below
I want to call this with named parameters not with the ordinal param
@Component
public MyClassDao extends AbstractDao(have the logic to get the DS){

final NamedParameterJdbcTemplete templete;

@Autowired
public MyClassDao(DataSource ds, NamedParameterJdbcTemplete templete){
super(dataSource);
this.templete = templete;
}

String queryString = "{ :"+ "RETURN_VALUE"+ " = call IS_EMPLOYEE_EXISTS ( :" + "EMP_ID" + ", :" +" EMP_NAME" + ", :" + "EMP_CATEGORY" +")}";

public Boolean callFunction(String empId,String empName, String empCat){

boolean result = false;

        try ( CallableStatement stmt = getDataSource().getConnection().prepareCall(IS_EMPLOYEE_EXISTS)) {

            stmt.registerOutParameter(RETURN_VALUE, Types.NUMERIC);
            stmt.setString(EMP_ID, empId); 
            stmt.setString(EMP_NAME, empName);
            stmt.setString(EMP_CATEGORY, empCat);

            stmt.execute();

            int returnValue = stmt.getInt(RETURN_VALUE);
            result = (returnValue == 1); // Interpret as boolean (1 for true, 0 for false)

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
}

I have tried some other approaches also which are also not working out

Try this:
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall;
// import ...

SimpleJdbcCallOperations employeeExistsCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
        .withFunctionName("IS_EMPLOYEE_EXISTS");

SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource()
        .addValue(EMP_ID, empId); 
        .addValue(EMP_NAME, empName);
        .addValue(EMP_CATEGORY, empCat);

Boolean employeeExists = employeeExistsCall.executeFunction(Boolean.class, params);

Or explicitly define parameters:
SimpleJdbcCallOperations employeeExistsCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
        .withFunctionName("IS_EMPLOYEE_EXISTS")
        .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
        .withNamedBinding()
        .withReturnValue()
        .declareParameters(
                new SqlOutParameter("return", Types.BOOLEAN),
                new SqlParameter("EMP_ID", Types.VARCHAR),
                new SqlParameter("EMP_NAME", Types.VARCHAR),
                new SqlParameter("EMP_CATEGORY", Types.VARCHAR)
        );

SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource()
        .addValue(EMP_ID, empId); 
        .addValue(EMP_NAME, empName);
        .addValue(EMP_CATEGORY, empCat);

Boolean employeeExists = employeeExistsCall.executeFunction(Boolean.class, params);


The above code won't work .it will give error "Invalid column type 16 " due to the the return value
